# Display inline images on social media

Tags: twitter

I'd like to produce small graphics (.png) that users can share on various social media sites (Twitter, Google+ and Facebook). Essentially, I'm thinking a button with a share URL should do the trick.

On Google+, I've been able to display a thumbnail with some text. On Facebook, the image comes in nicely on the timeline. However, on Twitter, it's still a link that needs to be clicked.

I think this is due to my site not being a "partner" ? Is there a partner site that would enable the remote upload and link (without account creation), with an inline display on Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Use Twitter Cards - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/types/photo-card
2. Actually post the image to Twitter.

You don't need to be a "partner" for either.

Comment: so, does that mean that I could have one page and that based on query string parameters, fill in the various meta tags necessary for the card? I fail to see how else this could be done as image files don't usually come with meta tags. I also don't see the point of creating individual files to enable the card.

Comment: Yes, there will need to be an HTML page with the appropriate meta-tags and an `<img>`.